# Convert GPS bearing to Cartesian angle

Tags: java, angles, bearing

I have two GPS coordinates:

- Location A `25.07507, 55.14012`.
- Location B `25.07571, 55.13975`.

The bearing between location A and location B is `332.9°`.

If we know that location A has a Cartesian point of `811.0, 1030.0`, and location B has a Cartesian point of `420.0, 58.0`, is there a way to find the angle between these two Cartesian points, which would be `332.9` as well?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: what software or programming language are you planning to use?

Comment: @IanTurton Java

Comment: @IanTurton forgot to mention, Java on Android app.

Comment: It's not safe to assume the Cartesian bearing is going to be the same as the geodesic bearing. Cartesian direction is not applicable to angular units (degrees lat/lon). Solving the angle and backangle between two geodetic points is one of [the two problems of geoedesy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesy). It involves iteratively solving a partial differential equation with lots of trig functions. I recommend using a library, not trying to solve this on your own. Cartesian bearing is just simple trig.